# Deleting reverse zone in windows 2003 DNS server

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller, reverse-dns

This is my first time posting here on server fault. The problem i am faced with is when i try to add another DC to my network i am getting a very weird error. After some countless hours and re-reading the error it points the the reverse up zone that is set up when you install the DNS on the win 2003 server. It will not let me delete it. I get the following error.

The zone cannot be deleted. The Active Directory Service is not available.

Which isn't true in the fact i have users on the network.Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Reverse lookup zones aren't required for AD and most certainly aren't created when you install the DNS role on a DC. Why don't you tell us the actual error message you're getting when you try to promote a new DC.

Answer (score 0):

Are you preparing the server for decommission by any chance?  I had a similar issue when trying to move Active Directory from 2003 to a new 2012 box at 2 sites.

3 questions:

1. I presume you are running ipv4?  If so, disable ipv6 on the 2012 box as it gets in the way & can cause issues.  I spent 3 wasted hours on an early install before I learn't that lesson.
2. Have you run adprep on the 03 box?
3. Have you run dcdiag on the 03 box & has everything gone smoothly?

Hope this helps.